# Wordpress not reading the wp_postmeta.meta_value

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem with word press not displaying the SEO title from All in One SEO plugin. I have looked at the wp_title() which then goes to the single_post_title() but can not see anything that is looking up the wp_postmeta.meta_value in the database only post_title.

Maybe this is a part of the plugin but where does the plugin overwrite the default behaviour of word press `<title>`.

Comment: within your single post, have you set the SEO Title? of that post?
in your template file just leave the title as <title><?php wp_title();?></title> and it will do the rest.

Comment: Sadly no this just removes the title and nothing is displayed. How do I find in word press where the problem is being caused from?

Comment: when your writing your post/page, All in one seo pack adds a custom meta box, under the write post panel, if its not there, up the top right hand side there will "Screen Options" click this and see if the all in one seo tick box is checked.? then within the meta box you will see the SEO post title, just enter your seo title here, and this should replace the standard one when you view the page..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your Theme:

- is wp_title() and wp_head() called, as I suppose All in one SEO-Pack is hooking into one of these functions
- does it use an own mechanism to generate a title?
- is a title generated in your Theme and the title from the All in one SEO-Pack is generated below, so it is not recognized?

If there is everything ok with your Theme, also the All in one SEO-Pack will work, i suppose. If not, deactivate all other Plugins to check if one of these is overwriting or hooking into the title functions, so that the All in one SEO-Pack can not take action.

Hope this helps.